# ErrorIrresolvableConflict when trying to delete attachments from email

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I have written a program to archive emails from Outlook using Microsoft Graph.
After archiving an email the program deletes the attachments of the email. Thereby the following exception is sometimes thrown:

> Status Code: PreconditionFailed Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException:
> Code: ErrorIrresolvableConflict Message: The send or update operation
> could not be performed because the change key passed in the request
> does not match the current change key for the item., Cannot save
> changes made to an item to store.SaveStatus: IrresolvableConflict
> PropertyConflicts:
>
> ClientRequestId: 97513ec2-a8bf-4ab4-a492-0f5e0ca0bf32

C# code:

```
    public void DeleteAttachments(List<string> attachmentIds)
    {
        foreach (var attachmentId in attachmentIds)
        {
            Task.Run(() => DeleteAttachmentAsync(attachmentId)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
    }

    private async Task DeleteAttachmentAsync(string id)
    {
        await GraphServiceClient
            .Users[CurrentUser.Id]
            .MailFolders[CurrentFolder.Id]
            .Messages[CurrentMessage.Id]
            .Attachments[id]
            .Request()
            .DeleteAsync();
    }
```

Is there a problem with this code?

Is there a possibility to delete all attachments of an email in one batch.

My observations when I tested the above code:
When testing with dozens of emails with attachments, the exception is sometimes thrown when an email has more than one attachment, but the removal of several attachments can also be successful.

Comment: According to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/attachment-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp), I'm afraid what you can do is executing an recursion of to get all the emails and delete the attachments one by one because there's not a batch delete method. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcbZR.png